# Next js and client data fetching

Tags: next.js

I want to make a request to the server from the client, but the problem is that if I reload the page in the console, I get an empty array and if I change something in the code (to start compilation), then the client receives data, can this be fixed?

```
const router = useRouter()
const { id } = router.query
const URL = `http://localhost:4500/theme/${id}`

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        if (id) {
            setLoad(true)
            const response = await fetch(URL)
            const data = await response.json()
            setData(data)
            setLoad(false)
        }
    }
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "useEffect" can be the cause of the problems. When the component is first rendered, it only runs once. When the component re-renders, the fetch request is just called once and is not updated. You might want to try adding your "id" to the "useEffect" array like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  
}, [id])
```

Its also a good idea to add some error handling. See modified code below:

```
const router = useRouter()
const { id } = router.query
const URL = `http://localhost:4500/theme/${id}`

const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      if (id) {
        setLoading(true)
        const response = await fetch(URL)
        const data = await response.json()
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
  fetchData()
}, [id])

if (loading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
}

return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
```

Every time the "id" prop changes, this will initiate a retrieve request, enabling the component to update and show the updated data. You can also add your preferred loading animation for better visualisation.